# Abnormal large delays between wasm-code getting stored and applied

Tags: parachain, kusama, runtime-upgrade

We had a runtime upgrade on kusama-parachain recently (9050 -> 9060), where the parachain stalled for 20min. Eventually, it self healed, but I find it abnormal as I have never seen such a big delay in the past runtime upgrades.

Therefore I want to post it here to see if we potentially did something wrong and/or other people have had similar situations.

I understand there's a 600 blocks upgrade delay on Kusama (which is ~1hr), but:

- here's [the block](https://litmus.subscan.io/block/273331?tab=event) where `ValidationFunctionStored` was emitted
- here's [the block](https://litmus.subscan.io/block/273405?tab=event) where `ValidationFunctionApplied` was emitted

It's 1hr25min in between, which is obviously more than 600 Kusama blocks.

Here's a screenshot of kusama parachain panel. I believe the "+10 mins" sign shows the upgrade went beyond scheduled blocks.

[image: screenshot on litmus]

From collator logs it just keeps importing the next block and managed to prepare it within 10ms, but it couldn't get it produced somehow (maybe blocked by relaychain verification?) The PoV that contains the new wasm is just 1,5MB.

For the full logs please check [here](https://github.com/litentry/litentry-parachain/issues/546#issuecomment-1118514438).

We had a very similar issue on rococo-parachain not long ago, but it wasn't able to heal itself and we never understood the root cause. The problem disappeared after a hard rococo restart, see https://github.com/litentry/litentry-parachain/issues/544

Some extra information about our setup:

- the new runtime was built with `polkadot-v0.9.19` branch, with srtools
- our collators are all located in Singapore right now, is this related?
- we have 4core CPU and 16G for collator hardware, I hope that's enough.